# Gulp loops for generate sprite by folder

Tags: gulp, css-sprites

I'm a Gulp newbie after many research, I don't find a solution for my problem.
My aim is to generate a sprite by folder with the name of the sprite will be the name of the folder.

Folder structure is:

```
-assets
   -images
      -icon
          -image-1.png
          -image-2.png
          -image-3.png
          -image-4.png
          -image-5.png
      -header
          -image-1.png
          -image-2.png
          -image-3.png
          -image-4.png
          -image-5.png
      -etc...
```

And I would like have a sprite by folder in another folder subassets :

```
-subassets
   -images
      - sprite-icon.png
      - sprite-header.png
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You will need to use e.g. the `gulp-folders` plugin to pass the folder names on each iteration https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-folders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`gulp-folders`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-folders) package, you can do, e.g.:

```
gulp.task('sprites', folder('assets/images', function (folder) {
    // your gulp task to create sprites...
    return gulp.src([
        path.join('assets/images', folder, '*.png')
        ], {
           base: './'
        })
        // sprite creation plugin stuff goes here...
        .pipe(gulp.dest('subassets/images/sprite-' + folder + '.png'));
}));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response and your reactivity

Comment: @Maxime absolutely- glad to help :)